# How to automatically create aliases for action parameters in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC application that have incredibly big URLs, to the point that it's frequently triggering "Bad Request"s, even with the web.config settings being maxed up for URL size, content size and so forth.

Part of the problem is that parameter names are often really big in my app. Specially when I have collection binding in which the parameter names are repeated over and over.

So, I though of changing the way ASP.NET finds names for action parameters, both while creating route parameters and when it's trying to bind it.

I don't want to go into the details of how I would shorten the URLs, because it's irrelevant.. but basically.. if no other property of the model starts with an `n`, `name` will become `n`. If there's another property that starts with `n`, it will be `n2`.

So the question is, how do I get started implementing such functionality? If you could please point me out to an existing solution that solves something similar I would be thankful.

Comment: Since you are dealing with routes you might consider some sort of custom RouteHandler. Top of my head. I've done it to intercept query params and obfuscate / deobfuscate.

Comment: Please be more clear. Are you talking about model binding? Can you give a schematic example of what you're talking about? Are these POST or GET requests?